# pyspark datastax cassandra connector keeps connecting to localhost

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect  pyspark to cassandra using datastax driver

```
 conf = SparkConf()\
.setAppName('Test') \
.setMaster('local[4]') \
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.150") 
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
options(table="test", keyspace="test_keyspace").load()
```

For some reason it keeps connecting to 127.0.0.1:9042 instead of 192.168.0.150

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All  
host(s) tried for query 
failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042  
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
[localhost/127.0.0.1] Cannot connect))
```

I am using spark 2.10 and running program as below

```
spark-submit --packages datastax:spark-cassan
dra-connector:2.0.0-RC1-s_2.11 test.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the issue in Spark 2.10 cassandra configuration is set as option in SqlContext.
code below works

```
sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.150").\
option("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "user"). \
option("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "password"). \
options(table="test_table", keyspace="test_space").load()
```